# Z3: models with Reals

Tags: z3

For this benchmark:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun s0 () Real)
(declare-fun s1 () Real)
(assert (> s0 s1))
(check-sat)
(get-value (s0))
(get-value (s1))
```

I'm getting:

```
sat
((s0 0.0))
((s1 0.0))
```

Is this a known issue? (This is using Z3 V3.2 both on Linux and Mac.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this was a bug in the model generator. The bug has been fixed.
The bug can be avoided using

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
```

If Z3 becomes too slow in quantifier free problems, then we can also add

```
(set-option :relevancy 0)
```